# Python's NumPy: Proper use of a tuple of axis numbers to permute the axes of higher dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Does anyone have an intuitive way of looking at how transposing higher dimensional arrays by passing tuples of axis numbers works?

Here's an example:

```
arr = np.arange(16).reshape((2, 2, 4))
```

arr

```
> array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

arr.transpose((1, 0, 2))

```
> array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

If `arr.transpose((1, 0))` would read "Transpose axis 1 with axis 0 (i.e. switch axis 1 with axis 0)"  then `arr.transpose((1, 0, 2))` would read...?

Comment: Have you read the description in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html)?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking. I'd just say `arr.transpose(1, 0, 2)` means "swap axes 0 and 1, leave axis 2 where it is." You might find geometric interpretations more intuitive.

Comment: There might not be an intuitive way because it isn't something we do in real life, especially in dimensions higher that 2.  It might help to start with a `(2,3,4)` array, and try different swaps.  With distinctive shapes and values it is easier to visualize the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *values* in the tuple refer to the axes as they were before you make the `transpose` call, the *indices* in the tuple refer to the axes as they are going to be after the call.

So `x.transpose( (2,1,3,0) )` will result in the previously third axis now being first, the previously second axis remaining second, the previously fourth axis now being third, and the previously first axis now being fourth and last.

Comment: Sure, I that's what it does.  But, given that could you predict what arr4d.transpose((1,0,2,3)) would look like if you were given arr4d = np.arange(120).reshape((2,3,4,5)).      A 3d case would have been easier, but I'm using your example.

Comment: @pefmath, um yes, `arr4d.transpose((1,0,2,3)).shape` would be `(3,2,4,5)`. Was that not clear from the docs and my answer? (I thought I understood your question, but I'm not so sure now anymore...)